# why system is always accessing the microphone now?

Tags: macos, privacy, microphone

Recently I noticed that system (not system preferences, but system itself) keeps the right to access the micro even if one is not using Siri nor dictation. Is this a recent issue? How to know exactly what process of "system" is using the microphone?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the list of apps that have access to the microphone and checked if any are running?

(You can see what apps have access in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Select Microphone.)

Answer (score 7):

At times the microphone indicator gets stuck and continues showing up in the Control Center even when no apps are using the mic, in which case you won’t see any specific app names in the Control Center.

To fix this, you can either reboot the system or just run the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

Answer (score 0):

If only "system" appears, one could suspect an app considered to be part of the system. In my case, it was the screen capture app. Somehow it was left running without any alert, and even if I had logged off and on twice. Some "feature" I guess, for screencasts.

Killing the screen capture processs from the terminal did the job.